# Finding possible weights allocation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, allocation

Given weight vector

```
w = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
```

Should result in

```
wg = [0.15 0.05 0.1  0.1  0.1; 
      0.15 0.1  0.05 0.1  0.1; 
      0.15 0.1  0.1  0.05 0.1; 
      0.15 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.05; 
      0.05 0.15 0.1  0.1  0.1; 
      0.1  0.15 0.5  0.1  0.1; ...]
```

so there will be the matrix with possible allocations so each element of `w` will increase and decrease to `0.05`.

I tried using loop, but it seems to be incorrect approach, because there is a situation when index exceeds matrix dimensions. Is it possible to use loop? Any solution? Thank you.

Comment: Please explain more thoroughly how you get `wg` from `w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with a loop:

```
w = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
n = length(w);

adj = [0.05*ones(n-1,1), -0.05*eye(length(w)-1)];

wg = bsxfun(@plus, w, adj);
for c = 2:n
   adj(:,[c-1, c]) = adj(:,[c, c-1]);
   wg = [wg; bsxfun(@plus, w, adj)];
end
```

which results in

```
wg =

   0.150000   0.050000   0.100000   0.100000   0.100000
   0.150000   0.100000   0.050000   0.100000   0.100000
   0.150000   0.100000   0.100000   0.050000   0.100000
   0.150000   0.100000   0.100000   0.100000   0.050000
   0.050000   0.150000   0.100000   0.100000   0.100000
   0.100000   0.150000   0.050000   0.100000   0.100000
   0.100000   0.150000   0.100000   0.050000   0.100000
   0.100000   0.150000   0.100000   0.100000   0.050000
   0.100000   0.050000   0.150000   0.100000   0.100000
   0.050000   0.100000   0.150000   0.100000   0.100000
   0.100000   0.100000   0.150000   0.050000   0.100000
   0.100000   0.100000   0.150000   0.100000   0.050000
   0.100000   0.050000   0.100000   0.150000   0.100000
   0.100000   0.100000   0.050000   0.150000   0.100000
   0.050000   0.100000   0.100000   0.150000   0.100000
   0.100000   0.100000   0.100000   0.150000   0.050000
   0.100000   0.050000   0.100000   0.100000   0.150000
   0.100000   0.100000   0.050000   0.100000   0.150000
   0.100000   0.100000   0.100000   0.050000   0.150000
   0.050000   0.100000   0.100000   0.100000   0.150000
```

Which is what I think you're after. It's probably possible without a loop as well but I'm sure this will suffice.

Comment: Yes. It's exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: But how it is possible to avoid situations, when allocation is negative. For example, if initial weights are w = 0,11 0,09 0,1 0,1 0,2 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1 0]. Thank you

Comment: @Adrian I don't what 
that means. Your problem is ill defined.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add/subtract each weight either -.05, 0 or .05 weight.
To cover all possibilities (3 for 5 elements in 5, total 3^5 options):

```
>> n = length( w );
>> [x{1:n}] = ndgrid( -1:1 );
>> x = cellfun( @(y) y(:), x, 'uni', 0 );
>> wg = bsxfun(@plus, w, [x{:}]*.05 );
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the sum of weights to be unaltered. You could just add `wg = wg(sum(wg,2)==sum(w),:);` at the end